# fix java logical error, user money does not deduct or add whether it lose or win

Tags: java, methods

I want to create a java dice game that use only Branching (if-else), Nested while loops, and Method (simple function and procedures).

The code run fine but when it comes to the result where is determine that how much money user have, it does not show anything, it only show the default money which is 100 so how to fix it?  Thank you so much, I am just a beginner so please do not mine me for my question. here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int umoney= 100;
            int lw;
            int roll1;
            int roll2;
            int bet ;
            System.out.println("You have "+ umoney+" dollars");
            while (umoney!=0) {
            bet = getBet(in, umoney);
            char user=getHighLow(in);
            roll1=getRoll();
            System.out.println("Die 1 rolls: "+roll1);
            roll2=getRoll();
            System.out.println("Die 2 rolls: "+roll2);
            System.out.println("Total of two diece is: " + (roll1+roll2));
            lw = determineWinnings(user, bet, (roll1+roll2));
            if (lw<0) {
                    System.out.println("You lost!");
            }
            else {
                    System.out.println("You won "+ lw+" dollars!");
                    umoney=umoney+lw;
            }
            }       
    }


    // Given a Scanner and a current maximum amount of money, prompt the user for
    // an integer representing the number of dollars that they want to bet.  This
    // number must be between 0 and to maximum number of dollars.  If the user enters
    // a number that is out of bounds, display an error message and ask again.
    // Return the bet to the calling program.
    private static int getBet(Scanner inScanner, int currentPool) {
            // Fill in the body
            System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
            int ubet= inScanner.nextInt();
            if (ubet==0) {
                    System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
            while (ubet<0 || ubet > currentPool) {
                    System.out.println("You must enter between 0 and "+ currentPool +" dollars");
                    System.out.println("You have "+ currentPool+" dollars");
                    System.out.println("Enter an amount to bet (0 to quit): ");
                    ubet=inScanner.nextInt();
                    if (ubet==0) {
                            System.out.println("Goodbye!");
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
            }      
            return ubet;
    }

    // Given a Scanner, prompt the user for a single character indicating whether they
    // would like to bet High ('H'), Low ('L') or Sevens ('S').  Your code should accept
    // either capital or lower case answers, but should display an error if the user attempts
    // to enter anything but one of these 3 values and prompt for a valid answer.
    // Return the character to the calling program.
    private static char getHighLow(Scanner inScanner) {
            // Fill in the body
            System.out.println("High, Low or Seven (H/L/S): ");
            char iuword= inScanner.next().charAt(0);
            while (iuword!='h' && iuword!='H' && iuword!='L' && iuword!='l' && iuword!='s' && iuword!='S') {
                    System.out.println("Invalid commad, Please enter again!");
                    System.out.println("High, Low or Seven (H/L/S): ");
                    iuword= inScanner.next().charAt(0);
            } return iuword;          
    }

    // Produce a random roll of a single six-sided die and return that value to the calling
    // program
    private static int getRoll() {

            int roll1 =(int)(6*Math.random())+1;               
            return roll1;
    }

    // Given the choice of high, low or sevens, the player's bet and the total result of
    // the roll of the dice, determine how much the player has won.  If the player loses
    // the bet then winnings should be negative.  If the player wins, the winnings should
    // be equal to the bet if the choice is High or Low and 4 times the bet if the choice
    // was Sevens.  Return the winnings to the calling program.
    private static int determineWinnings(char highLow, int bet, int roll) {


            int result;
            if (highLow=='H' || highLow=='h') {
                    if (roll<7) {
                            result =-1*bet;
                    }
                    else {
                            result=bet;
                    }
            }
            if (highLow=='L'|| highLow=='l') {
                    if (roll>7) {
                            result=-1*bet;
                    }
                    else {
                            result=bet;
                    }
            }
            if (highLow=='S' || highLow=='s') {
                    result =4*bet;
                    }
            else {

                    result = -1*bet;
            }
            return result;               
    }
```

Comment: Also put the sample out which ur expecting?? The code is huge.. Appreciate if your question is a bit more precise.

Comment: Please indent your code properly. The list all the places where you print the current money, and check which ones are inside a loop or print at the end of the program.

Comment: @SamDJava this is how the code look when run http://i58.tinypic.com/2w7ll4l.png which is doenst not match the expectation.

Comment: @Mat Thank you so much, it work right now!! and for the code writing style, it would be appreciate if you mind to show the way to write it neatly as i'm just a beginner that why i wrote all over the place like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the code.

1. The line `umoney = umoney + lw` needs to go after the if-else block. You want to add wins And losses, not just wins :p
2. You have missed one if condition in determineWinnings - The `highLow == 'S'` needs to be followed by `if (roll == 7)`